# Does this Javascript cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory

Notice in the following code, the child gets a reference to its parent.  What happens when the original reference to parent is set to null?  Does the parent stay around since there still is an active reference from the child?

**Javascript**

```
var parent = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.runme = function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = 'run me';
  }

  self.child = new child(self);

  return self;
}
var child = function(parent) {
  var self = this;
  var parent = parent;
  self.event = function() {
    parent.runme();
  }
}
var p = new parent();
p.child.event();
p = null;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="output">
  old value
</div>
```

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/8fvy5r4f/

Comment: Have you tried running any console performance logging yet to see what your memory load looks like? Is there a specific problem you are encountering that leads to to believe you have memory leak issues?

Comment: *What happens when the original reference to parent is set to null?* - GC will clean it asap

Comment: No, I just want to know if, in general, the above pattern causes a leak.

Comment: "*Does the parent stay around since there still is an active reference from the child?*" - yes. "*Does this Javascript cause a memory leak?*" - No. The child is collected, and so will the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var p = new parent();
p.child.event();
p = null;
```

Eventually both parent and child will be garbage collected because neither parent nor child will be "reachable" anymore. There's no memory leak here. That's assuming you are dealing with a modern JavaScript interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't because most garbage collectors are based on the idea of [reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Reachability_of_an_object). Basically, if the object isn't reachable from the root(s) of the graph then it can be safely collected. After initialization you create a graph like this:

```
root -> parent <-> child
```

Then after `p = null` you get this:

```
root X parent <-> child
```

Since neither `parent` nor it's dependents are reachable, they can all be safely collected.